# Encoding a binary vector in a suitable way in Matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, encoding, binary

The context and the problem below are *only* examples that can help to visualize the question.

> **Context:** Let's say that I'm continously generating random binary vectors *G* with length 1x64 (whose values are either 0 or 1).
>
> **Problem:** I don't want to check vectors that I've already checked, so I want to create a kind of table that can identify what vectors are already generated before.

So, **how can I identify each vector in an optimized way?**

My first idea was to convert the binary vectors into decimal numbers. Due to the maximum length of the vectors, I would need `2^64 = 1.8447e+19` numbers to encode them. That's huge, so I need an alternative.

I thought about using hexadecimal coding. In that case, if I'm not wrong, I would need `nchoosek(16+16-1,16) = 300540195` elements, which is also huge.

So, there are better alternatives? For example, a kind of hash function that can identify that vectors without repeating values?

Comment: Are you going to actually generate `2^64` different vectors? If it's fewer than `2^32`, I'd just encode them as `uint64`

Comment: The only hash table I know of that's implemented in MATLAB is `containers.Map`. I don't know how efficient a map will be in this instance, but it's worth a try. Trying to create even a bitset of 2^64 bits is probably overly memory-intensive.

Comment: @Suever I'mt not performing an exhaustive search, so it is quite improbable that I'll reach the `2^32`. Thanks for the sugerence!

Comment: @beaker Effectively, `containers.Map` is what I wanted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have 64 bit values (or vectors) and you need a data structure in order to efficiently check if a new value is already existing?

Hash sets or binary trees come to mind, depending on if ordering is [important or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846468/hash-table-vs-balanced-binary-tree).

Matlab has a hash table in [containers.Map](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/map-containers.html).

Here is a example:

```
tic;
n = 1e5; % number of random elements
keys = uint64(rand(n, 1) * 2^64); % random uint64

% check and add key if not already existing (using a containers.Map)
map = containers.Map('KeyType', 'uint64', 'ValueType', 'logical');
for i = 1 : n
    key = keys(i);
    if ~isKey(map, key)
        map(key) = true;
    end
end
toc;
```

However, depending on why you really need that and when you really need to check, the Matlab function `unique` might also be something for you.

Just throwing out duplicates once at the end like:

```
tic;
unique_keys = unique(keys);
toc;
```

is in this example 300 times faster than checking every time.

Comment: Awesome answer! `containers.Map` adapts perfectly to what I wanted. In addition, it allows me to set `double` values asigned to each key :)