# C# Read text file content and split it alphabetically

Tags: c#, list, class, file-io

I am trying to write an agenda. A little form is diplayed for each contact (this within a MDI parent form). With my current code all contacts are written to a file; the way I am presenting info, displays all contacts at once (which certainly would not be appealing to end users).

Definitely I need to present contacts alphabetically. The first field in each line of the file is the contact lastname, which can help me to sort. Where this rookie is stuck is, how to extract lines based on the first letter of the lastname so I can present info as in a real agenda?

I saw a question from someone else, the answer was sublists and a "group-by" function. However there was no explanation of the code, then it all was like chinese to me.

I was thinking maybe splitting my "all-contacts-file", into small files based on first letter of last name (but that would be too many little files, maybe not a good practice?). If this was not a bad idea, how could be accomplished?

I created a class "Person". And with this code I add a new contact:

```
private void btn_CM_addNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _contact.FirstName = txt_CM_name.Text;
    _contact.LastName = txt_CM_lastName.Text;
    //Person.lista.Add(_contact);
    StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("C:\\CA_Contacs.txt", true);
    file.WriteLine(_contact.ToString());
    file.Close();
    this.Close();
}
```

With this code I display the "contact cards":

```
if ((new FileInfo("C:\\CA_Contacs.txt").Exists == true))
{
    var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead("C:\\CA_Contacs.txt"));
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        Person _contact = new Person();
        var line = reader.ReadLine();
        var attributes = line.Split(',');
        _contact.LastName = attributes[0]; 
        _contact.FirstName = attributes[1];

        ContactCard contactCardItem = new ContactCard();
        contactCardItem.MdiParent = this;
        contactCardItem.Text = _contact.LastName + ", " + _contact.FirstName;
        contactCardItem.Contact = _contact;
        contactCardItem.Show();
        this.LayoutMdi(MdiLayout.TileVertical);
    }
}
```

What approach would you suggest to the contacts can be displayed alphabetically?

In other words, how to extract from the file all the lines that start with "A" or "a", put all those lines in their own group (list, sub-list, file, other structure that you suggest) so I can later present only that group, not all the contacts in the "CA_Contacs.txt" file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at LINQ, it is very powerful for this sort of thing. I would recommend you to not only copy and paste but actually learn what these lines mean.

This line of code will give you exactly what you need:

```
var contacts = from contact in (from ele in File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\\your.file")
                 // local variable with the splitted name
                 let name = line.Split(',') 
                 // Get a new Person-object
                 select new Person(){ LastName = name[0], FirstName = name[1] })
               // Group the Person-objects by the first letter of their last name
               group contact by contact.LastName.First() into g
               // Order them by their "key", ie A, B, C instead of random order.
               order by g.Key
               // Return the grouping we have created
               select g;
```

You can use it like this:

```
foreach (var contactGroup in contacts) {
  var header = contactGroup.Key; // ie 'A', 'B' etc
  // do something with header
  foreach (var contact in contactGroup)
  {
    // do something with contact (a Person-type instance)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I will first understand what your proposed code does and then integrate it to my project :)

Comment: Hi, rookie question: How is the key defined?

Comment: @DMS This line: `group contact by contact.LastName.First() into g` groups all contacts into groups defined by contact.LastName.First() (ie the key), does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks, I think I see it now: "by contact.LastName.First()" ... means look at the First char in contact.LastName

Answer (score 1):

When looping through and reading the lines of you text file, instead of immediately creating your 'ContactCard's, build a Generic Collection of some kind (List, Dictionary, etc). This object will give you powerful methods such as .Sort().

After your Collection object is built and sorted, then loop through and create your 'ContactCard's.

Here is stackoverflow detailing Collection types:

[Where can I learn about the various types of .NET lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198079/where-can-i-learn-about-the-various-types-of-net-lists)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Bo TX' answer:

After having built your collection, you can use Linq to query it, e. q.

```
using System.Linq;
.....


IEnumerable<ContactCard> contacts = ...;
```

=> object built / filled (see above)

```
IEnumerable<ContactCard> contactsWithA = contacts.Where(cc => cc.LastName.ToLower().StartsWith("a"));
```

Comment: Thanks macrobbsen, certainly this will be useful.