# Why does sorted list have to have a key value pair?

Tags: .net, generics, collections

If I just want a sorted list of just dates, integers, or doubles is it really necessary to have to define a SortedList(of Integer, Integer)?

Seems intriguing to me, but may just be trival. I'd prefer just to use a SortedList(of Integer).

(This question is in relation to the .Net generic collections)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a SortedList<T> class in .net ? (not SortedList<Key,Value> which is actually a kind of SortedDictionnary)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389813/is-there-a-sortedlistt-class-in-net-not-sortedlistkey-value-which-is-act)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The next version of .NET (4.0) will have the [`SortedSet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedset-1) class that exactly does what you want. Until then, encapsulating [`SortedList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedlist-2) gets closest – unless you want to implement an own class to do this, or use external collection libraries (e.g. [C5](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/) which has a `SortedArray` and a `TreeSet` class).

Comment: SortedSet will not add an element that is equal to the one already in the set, as the set theory requires. A SortedList should be able to handle multiple instances of the same value and sort them correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regular `List<T>` and call `Sort` on it.

Comment: This can be inefficient for large lists if sorting frequently; also, you have to remember to sort it every time it changes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's necessary, because that's how the API was designed. :-)

But it's not hard to just make your own `SortedList<T>` that uses `SortedList<K,V>`. 5 lines of code?

```
class SortedList<T> : IEnumerable<T> {
    SortedList<T,int> _list = new SortedList<T,int>();
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() { return _list.Keys.GetEnumerator(); }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return this.GetEnumerator();  }
    public void Add(T v) { _list.Add(v, 1); }
    public int Count { get { return _list.Count; } }
}
```

Only problem is, `SortedList` can't handle dups.

Comment: Just need to also implement non-generic ienumerable.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760322/troubles-implementing-ienumerablet .  I've edited it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted list sorts on the key and not on the values.  From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.aspx)

> The elements of a SortedList object
>   are sorted by the keys either
>   according to a specific IComparer
>   implementation specified when the
>   SortedList is created or according to
>   the IComparable implementation
>   provided by the keys themselves. In
>   either case, a SortedList does not
>   allow duplicate keys.

So its basically a dictionary class that supports sorting. `List` on the other hand sorts on values

Answer (score -1):

I think `HashSet<int>` may suit your needs.