# automapper mapping collections of objects

Tags: c#, automapper, dto

The following exception thrown during mapping collection of DTOs to the collection of Models:
A first chance exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in mscorlib.dll Additional information: Method 'GetEnumerator' in type IEnumerable is not implemented. The structure is as follows:

```
  class UnauthorizedItemsDto { InspectableItemDto[] PeerToPeerApplications { get; set; } } public interface IUnauthorizedItems { IEnumerable<IInspectableItem> PeerToPeerApplications { get; } }
class UnauthorizedItems : IUnauthorizedItems
{

private RangeObservableCollection<IInspectableItem> _peerToPeerApplications;
        private RangeObservableCollection<IInspectableItem> PeerToPeerApplicationsImpl
        {
            get
            {
                return _peerToPeerApplications ??
                       (_peerToPeerApplications = new RangeObservableCollection<IInspectableItem>());
            }
        }
        public IEnumerable<IInspectableItem> PeerToPeerApplications
        {
            get { return PeerToPeerApplicationsImpl; }
        }
}
```

All relevant mappings for single items are added inside the mapping profile

Comment: This [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760322/troubles-implementing-ienumerablet) may have some input for you. Just check it.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the case. I'm not providing my own implementation of IEnumerable<T> but rather using BCL types or derivations of thereof.
I don't understand whether AutoMapper requires that the collections in the target object are concrete types instead of interfaces.