# TreeNode Creation Errors

Tags: c#, error-handling, treenode

I'm trying to use TreeNodes to create a Tree like structure in code. I'm not all that familiar with TreeNodes at all. I did some searching beforehand but I still don't feel like I understand exactly what I am doing.

I am creating a Game in Unity using C#. I'm using XML to create dialogue and I want to store the different options from the different choices in a Tree-like structure.

A visual representation of this would be like:

-------------------------------choice a  ---------------------------   choice b  --------------------------------

```
                /--------|--------\          /--------|--------\

            choice d  choice e  choice f choice g  choice h  choice i
```

and so on.

```
public class TreeNode<T> : IEnumerable<TreeNode<T>> 
{
    public T Data {get; set;}
    public TreeNode<T> Parent { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TreeNode<T>> Children {get; set;}

    public TreeNode(T data) {
        this.Data = data;
        this.Children = new LinkedList<TreeNode<T>>();
    }

    public TreeNode<T> AddChild(T child) {
        TreeNode<T> childNode = new TreeNode<T>(child) {Parent = this};
        this.Children.Add (childNode);
        return childNode;
    }
}
```

Currently I am getting the error `TreeNode<T>' does not implement interface member`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable>.GetEnumerator()'.

I'm not entirely sure what that error even means, any help would be appreciated.

My first time posing a question in StackOverFlow so if this is in the wrong spot, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Were you able to resolve your issue?

Comment: Yes! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the line where you declare that `TreeNode<T>` (will) implement `IEnumerable<TreeNode<T>>`. In order to properly implement that interface, the class needs to have an implementation of all the methods the interface exposes.

```
public class TreeNode<T> : IEnumerable<TreeNode<T>>
```

Remove `: IEnumerable<TreeNode<T>>` and it'll compile correctly. Unless of course you want to implement that interface, then you need to add implementations of all the IEnumerable methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can either try removing the inherited `: IEnumerable<TreeNode<T>>` or you would need to implement the `System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` method.

See [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760322/troubles-implementing-ienumerablet) thread for some extra reading on the error, and possibly some further understanding.

Quoted 
"**You did not implement System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator.
When you implement the generic IEnumerable you have to also implement System.Collections.IEnumerable's GetEnumerator.**"