# C# alternative for the C++ STL set<T>

Tags: c#, sorting

I'm looking for a sorted data structure, that will be similar to the STL set(T).
I found SortedList, but it requires (key, val), I'm looking for something like List(string)  - only sorted.

I found on the web Spring.Collections, but my framework does not recognize it.

Is there a simple SortedSet I could use in the regular basic framework?

Thanks,
Gal

Comment: a List isn't a Set. Do you want to allow duplicates?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a sorted collection type in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196512/is-there-a-sorted-collection-type-in-net)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with A System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary. Here's a good article: [Dictionarys and sorting](http://dotnetperls.com/sort-dictionary-values)

**Edit:** The SortedDictionary seems even [better](http://dotnetperls.com/sorteddictionary).

Comment: Thanks. But this is exactly what i was trying to avoid: having <key, val>. I'm looking for a sorted data structure with only value, like List<string>, but I guess there isn't any, so I'll use your solution. :-)

Answer (score 7):

A SortedSet < T > introduced in .NET 4.0 is what you are looking for, see MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070(VS.100).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Also `List<T>` can be sorted. It is not sorted by default, but you can sort it, even with custom sorting algorithms if you so wish.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing built into the framework other than [`SortedDictionary<K,V>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) and [`SortedList<K,V>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.aspx).

The [C5 Collections](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/) library has several sorted collections. One of the following should do the trick, depending on your exact requirements: [`SortedArray<T>`](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/Release1.1/c5doc/types/C5.SortedArray_1.htm), [`TreeBag<T>`](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/Release1.1/c5doc/types/C5.TreeBag_1.htm) or [`TreeSet<T>`](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/Release1.1/c5doc/types/C5.TreeSet_1.htm).

There's also [Power Collections](http://powercollections.codeplex.com/), which provides `OrderedBag<T>` and `OrderedSet<T>` collections.

Answer (score 0):

There is a System.Collections.SortedList or System.Collections.Generic.SortedList which is always sorted.
Or you can use the Array.Sort method to sort ar defined moments in time.

Answer (score -1):

How about using a List<> and calling the Sort method?

**Not an extension but try this**

```
public class SortedList<T>: List<T>
{
    public SortedList(): base()
    {
    }
    public SortedList(IEnumerable<T> collection): base(collection)
    {
    }
    public SortedList(int capacity)
        : base(capacity)
    {
    }

    public void AddSort(T item)
    {
        base.Add(item);
        this.Sort();
    }
}
```

It's only a starting point, but adds a new method AddSort.

An extension method would be used to alter the List<>.Add method and call the sort on the end of it.

**Using extension method**

Place the following in a namespace accessible by your code:

```
public static class ListExtension
{
    public static void AddSort<T>(this List<T> list, T item)
    {
        list.Add(item);
        list.Sort();
    }
}
```

You can the use code such as:

```
List<int> newList = List<int>();
newList.AddSort(6);
newList.AddSort(4);
newList.AddSort(3);
```

And the values will be:

newList[0] == 3
newList[1] == 4
newList[3] == 6

You can also just use newList.Add and the list is then sorted when you call newList.AddSort

Comment: This has a complexity penalty, it would be quicker to use a sorted data structure that inserts the values in a sorted way to begin with.

Comment: Could you not use an extension method to encompass this behaviour?

Comment: Well, using a sorted data structure that inserts the values in a sorted way to begin with is one way - like SortedDictionary, but then you have to use <keys, values>, and I was looking for something simpler with only <values>...

Comment: @Gal: have added a new class in my answer based on List<> it's very rough and ready, but does what you want. Ideally I was looking at an extension to the List<>.Add() method which would be my preferred route.

Comment: @Gal just added an example entension method to the List<> class for you.

Comment: @Chris, Thanks for your efforts, but your solution is N*N*Log(N), because If you have N AddSort() calls, for each call you do Sort() in N*Log(N). Building a sorted data structure shouldn't take more than N*Log(N).