# What is comparison operator for references?

Tags: c#, .net

I can create set of pointers in c++ like that:

```
std::set<Data*> data_set;
```

Is there similar way to write that:

```
SortedSet<Data> data_set;
```

Edit: I want to use similar order logic in c#. Data is simple derived class of Object.

Comment: might be usefull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072786/c-sharp-alternative-for-the-c-stl-sett

Comment: Could you elaborate on what it is you're looking to do? If you want a sorted set in C# with a different sorting than what ever `SortedSet` provides, implement the `IComparer` interface in a class and override the `Compare` method.

Comment: If you want to have a set of unique object instances when those objects don't have a logical order then you should be using a `HashSet`, not a `SortedSet`.

Comment: Yes, I just want set of unique object instances

Comment: Then you need to say that in your quesiton, rather than asking for something notably different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [`HashSet`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx). A set is a collection that contains no duplicate elements

```
HashSet<Data> data_set = new HashSet<Data>();
data_set.Add(new Data());
```

Comment: I think he is confused about comparing references in C#, he isn't trying to find what type of collection he should be using.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases C# isn't explicit about pointers and references like C++ is. If you create a collection of objects, however, it'll always implicitly be a collection of *references to* objects (note that I said "objects" in this case; value types are treated differently). (In most cases C# uses references rather than pointers *per se* - see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2yzs44b.aspx) for an exception to this). You can then do reference equality with the "==" operator.

The C# code you provided will actually have a similar effect to the C++ code you supply (except that, of course, you won't have to be explicit about the pointer/reference).