# Searching for data structure with fast search and small size

Tags: c#, list, serialization, data-structures, hashtable

I'm searching for data structure to store list of unique indices (integers). The most important features for me are:
 - fast checking if value exists in set of values - like in hashtable
 - small size in memory and after serialization - like array
It should of course support adding, removing elements, but performance of this actions aren't significiant.

Is there any structure in framework that works in this way? Or I should create it?

Example of use:
I have class for user and in this class few (~20) lists of various data. (accesses, privilages, documents etc). I need to store user data in cache for fast access during postbacks - querying DB each time is very slow. Integers are indices in db,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a sorted collection type in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196512/is-there-a-sorted-collection-type-in-net)

Comment: Do you mean behavior like List<int>?

Comment: Are the indices going to be within a certain range?  i.e. I assume they are positive values, but do you know a priori that they're going to be less than some value N?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for HashSet<T> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx

It's implemented so that it provides O(1) lookups (or so the documentation says, however I suspect its really an amortized O(1) since its implemented with Hashtables...) and supports many set operations.

I am not sure of its serialized form, but I will investigate it further. If you really want it to serialize to an array you could always do

```
var mySet = new HashSet<T>(new []{ 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5 });
Serialize(mySet.ToArray());
```

and then to deserialize just create a HashSet from the serialized array.

Comment: [`HashSet<T>.Contains()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356440.aspx) is O(1) according to the documentation, not O(log n)

Comment: Yes, thats correct. I was thinking of SortedSet(T) which is implemented using Red-Black trees.

Comment: You are right - I forgot about variants of dictionary. It is damn fast, but size after serialization is aprox 2 times larger than serialized List. But I think that it is what i'm searching for:)