# Ordering a filtered list of objects according to the full list

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I have a `List<object> fullList` and a `List<object> filteredList` (that contains only distinct items and all the items in `filteredList` can be found in `fullList` - but not vice versa)

Now sometimes in my program I am calling `filteredList.Add(fullList[#]);` and have come to realize that I want to maintain the same order in `filteredList` that exists in `fullList`. What is the best way to do this?

Here's one solution I thought of (but I'm wondering if there is a better way):

```
public void AddToFilteredList(object input)
{
    int index = 0;
    foreach (object ob in fullList)
    {
        if (filteredList.Contains(ob))
        {
            if (fullList.IndexOf(input) > fullList.IndexOf(ob))
                index++;
            else
            {
                filteredList.Insert(index, input);
                return;
            }
        }   
    }

    filteredList.Add(input);
}
```

Comment: Keep them sorted

Comment: use SortedList<T> filteredList or List.Add(items[i]).Sort(x => x.currentSortAttribute) ...?

Comment: @mjwills It can be sorted in a variety of different ways. Basically, I'm wanting to know if there is a way to sort `filteredList` based on `fullList`. I don't want to have to figure out what properties sort `fullList` and then sort `filteredList` based on those same properties

Comment: @derekantrican See `new SortedList<T>(comparer)`. You can also use `list.BinarySearch` to find the correct location to insert an item (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12172412/932418)

Comment: @mjwills `fullList` can change over time. It can be reloaded or sorted differently. Obviously in each of these situations, `filteredList` would have to be modified

Comment: @mjwills No. Neither list will ever have duplicates. `fullList` as just a matter-of-fact and `filteredList` because I check to see if it has items before I put them into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `fullList` can change over time. It can be reloaded or sorted
>   differently. Obviously in each of these situations, `filteredList`
>   would have to be modified

If `fullList` can change its order over time then I would encourage you to think about the problem in a slightly different way. You don't so much want a 'sorted list' as 'my original list but with some of the items removed'.

I would suggest declaring:

```
HashSet<object> subsetOfFullList
```

And adding entries to it rather than adding entries to `filteredList`.

Then, when you need `filteredList` then generate it (on the fly) using `Where` (which will maintain order). Something like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var fullList = new List<object> { 1, "bob2", "bob3", 4 };

            var subsetOfFullList = new HashSet<object> { fullList[3], fullList[1] };

            IReadOnlyList<object> filteredList = fullList.Where(z => subsetOfFullList.Contains(z)).ToList();

            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", filteredList));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So is it the `Where` that is doing the sorting here?

Comment: No, you get the sorting for free since `Where` will return the data in the order it exists in `fullList`. I assume you you don't so much want a 'sorted list' as 'my original list but with some of the items removed'.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was asking. `Where` is "sorting" simply because it goes through `fullList` in order. It's an interesting approach. I think I would just put that line in a `get` for `filteredList`, but that's just me

Answer (score 1):

I would create a wrapper class and keep both list synched as @L.B commented. That way compexity of adding reduces from `O(n)` to `O(log n)`

```
public class MyList<T>
{
    List<T> _FullList = new List<T>();
    List<T> _FilteredList = new List<T>();

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        Insert(_FullList, item);
        if(somecondition)
            Insert(_FilteredList, item);
    }

    public void Remove(T item)
    {
        _FullList.Remove(item);
        _FilteredList.Remove(item);
    }

    void Insert(List<T> list, T item)
    {
        var index = list.BinarySearch(item);
        if (index < 0) index = ~index;
        list.Insert(index, item);
    }

    //other methods needed 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use a `SortedList` for your `filteredList` using as the key the index in the `fullList`:

```
var fullListWithIndex = fullList.Select((f,i) => new { f, i });
```

Then you can filter the `fullListWithIndex` to keep the index:

```
var filteredList = new SortedList<int, typeoff>();

foreach (var fi in fullListWithIndex.Where(fi => test(fi.f)))
    filteredList.Add(fi.i, fi.f);
```

Then you can add new items to the `filteredList` in the right position:

```
filteredList.Add(num, fullList[num]);
```

And you can use `filteredList.Values` where you would use `filteredList` before.

If you like extension methods, `ToSortedList` can be nice to have:

```
public static SortedList<TKey, TValue> ToSortedList<TObj, TKey, TValue>(this IEnumerable<TObj> src, Func<TObj, TKey> keySelector, Func<TObj, TValue> valueSelector) {
    var ans = new SortedList<TKey, TValue>();

    foreach (var srcObj in src)
        ans.Add(keySelector(srcObj), valueSelector(srcObj));

    return ans;
}

public static SortedList<TObj, TObj> ToSortedList<TObj>(this IEnumerable<TObj> src) => ToSortedList(src, x => x, x => x);
public static SortedList<TKey, TObj> ToSortedList<TKey, TObj>(this IEnumerable<TObj> src, Func<TObj, TKey> keySelector) => ToSortedList(src, keySelector, x => x);
```

Now you have

```
var filteredList = fullListWithIndex.Where(fi => test(fi.f).ToSortedList(fi => fi.i, fi => fi.f);
```